# highcharts include multiple charts in foreach

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am working in ASP.NET and have a foreach loop.  I want to add a new highchart in each iteration of my loop. I'm not getting any errors, but only the first chart draws and it draws just kind of not showing anything.

This is what I have:

```
@foreach (Review r in @Model.Reviews)
{

    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; width: 70%;">
        @Html.ActionLink(@r.Business.Name, "BusinessDetail", new { id = @r.Business.ID }, new { @class = "business-link" })
    </div>


    <div style="width: 70%;" id="review-container">
        <p>@r.Text</p>
        <center style="margin-bottom: 25px;">

            <div id='container1' style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        $('#container1').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01)',
                                plotBorderWidth: 0,
                                plotShadow: false
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Browser<br>shares',
                                align: 'center',
                                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                                y: 50
                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                pie: {
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        distance: -50,
                                        style: {
                                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                                            color: 'white',
                                            textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    startAngle: -90,
                                    endAngle: 90,
                                    center: ['50%', '75%']
                                }
                            },
                            series: [{
                                type: 'pie',
                                name: 'Vote Count',
                                data: [
                                    ['Useful', @r.UsefulVoteCount],
                                    ['Cool', @r.CoolVoteCount],
                                    ['Funny', @r.FunnyVoteCount],

                                ]
                            }]
                        });
                    });

                </script>
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
</center>
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is looping through `r`s but you are only ever creating a chart in `$('#container1').highcharts(...)`. You need to create a new container and call a new `highcharts` to generate the chart. There are many ways to do this.

Comment: oh, so maybe just increment the id of the container on each loop through and then call highcharts on that new container?